# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException in some devices

Tags: sqliteexception

The application was working well, but became closed on some devices and this code for the application

my code is:

```
 public List<item> getListProduct() {

        item product = null;
        List<item> productList = new ArrayList<>();
        openDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tablo", null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            product = new item(cursor.getInt(0),
                               cursor.getString(1),
                               cursor.getString(2),
                               cursor.getString(3),
                               cursor.getString(4),
                               cursor.getString(5),
                               cursor.getInt(6));
            productList.add(product);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        closeDatabase();
        return productList;
    }
```

i get this error

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException
```

any helpe

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. Can you show the entire stacktrace? SQLiteException is very generic.

Comment: :Caused by: android.database.scilite.SQLiteException 
. at 
(Native Method:0) 
. at 
(SQLiteConnection.java:948) 
at 
(SQLiteConnection.java:559) 
. at 
(SQLiteSession.java:603) 
. at 
(SQLitePrograrn.java:63) 
. at 
(SQLiteQuery.java:37) 
. at (SQLiteDirectCursorDriverjava:46) 
. at (SQLiteDatabase.java:1493) 
. at (SQLiteDatabase.java:1427) 
at 
(databaseClass.java:60) 
(at .(windows_asila.java:126 
. at (Activity.java:7458) 
. at (Activity.java:7448) 
. at (Instrumentation.javal 286) 
. at (ActivityThreadjava:3409)